# Writing class for different JSON files

Tags: json, flutter, android-studio, class, dart

I have recently started my journey in Flutter(Dart). I am trying to build an application which fetches some JSON information using an API call.

I have successfully written a code for the following JSON file

```
[
  {
    "on_api": "1",
    "tl_api": "10",
    "pl1_api": "Smoor Chocolates Lounge",
    "pl2_api": "Vasant Nagar",
    "dl1_api": "MySoftwareCompany Software Pvt. Ltd.",
    "dl2_api": "Cunningham Road, Bengaluru - 560052",
    "fn_api": "Snehanshu",
    "ln_api": "Bhattacharya",
    "cn_api": "0123456789",
    "eid_api": "snehanshu@anyemailexample.com"
  },
  {
    "on_api": "1",
    "tl_api": "10",
    "pl1_api": "Smoor Chocolates Lounge",
    "pl2_api": "Vasant Nagar",
    "dl1_api": "MySoftwareCompany Software Pvt. Ltd.",
    "dl2_api": "Cunningham Road, Bengaluru - 560052",
    "fn_api": "Snehanshu",
    "ln_api": "Bhattacharya",
    "cn_api": "0123456789",
    "eid_api": "snehanshu@anyemailexample.com"
  },
  {
    "on_api": "1",
    "tl_api": "10",
    "pl1_api": "Smoor Chocolates Lounge",
    "pl2_api": "Vasant Nagar",
    "dl1_api": "MySoftwareCompany Software Pvt. Ltd.",
    "dl2_api": "Cunningham Road, Bengaluru - 560052",
    "fn_api": "Snehanshu",
    "ln_api": "Bhattacharya",
    "cn_api": "0123456789",
    "eid_api": "snehanshu@anyemailexample.com"
  },
  {
    "on_api": "1",
    "tl_api": "10",
    "pl1_api": "Smoor Chocolates Lounge",
    "pl2_api": "Vasant Nagar",
    "dl1_api": "MySoftwareCompany Software Pvt. Ltd.",
    "dl2_api": "Cunningham Road, Bengaluru - 560052",
    "fn_api": "Snehanshu",
    "ln_api": "Bhattacharya",
    "cn_api": "0123456789",
    "eid_api": "snehanshu@anyemailexample.com"
  },
  {
    "on_api": "1",
    "tl_api": "10",
    "pl1_api": "Smoor Chocolates Lounge",
    "pl2_api": "Vasant Nagar",
    "dl1_api": "MySoftwareCompany Software Pvt. Ltd.",
    "dl2_api": "Cunningham Road, Bengaluru - 560052",
    "fn_api": "Snehanshu",
    "ln_api": "Bhattacharya",
    "cn_api": "0123456789",
    "eid_api": "snehanshu@anyemailexample.com"
  }
]
```

Here is its element class

```
class Element {
  Element({
    this.onApi,
    this.tlApi,
    this.pl1Api,
    this.pl2Api,
    this.dl1Api,
    this.dl2Api,
    this.fnApi,
    this.lnApi,
    this.cnApi,
    this.eidApi,
  });

  String onApi;
  String tlApi;
  String pl1Api;
  String pl2Api;
  String dl1Api;
  String dl2Api;
  String fnApi;
  String lnApi;
  String cnApi;
  String eidApi;

  factory Element.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Element(
    onApi: json["order_number"],
    tlApi: json["tl_api"],
    pl1Api: json["pl1_api"],
    pl2Api: json["pl2_api"],
    dl1Api: json["dl1_api"],
    dl2Api: json["dl2_api"],
    fnApi: json["fn_api"],
    lnApi: json["ln_api"],
    cnApi: json["cn_api"],
    eidApi: json["eid_api"],
  );
}
```

Here is its api calling code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:smoorapplication/src/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:smoorapplication/src/model/elements.dart';

Future<List<Element>> apiGetOrder() async{
  var response = await get(Uri.parse(MOCK_API_SMOOR_1));
  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<Element> elements = <Element>[];
  for(var i in jsonData){
    Element element = Element.fromJson(i);
    elements.add(element);
  }
  print(elements.length);
}
```

I want the api call code and element class code for this kind of messy JSON file

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": 3927180738697,
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Order/00000",
      "app_id": 580111,
      "browser_ip": "122.172.179.207",
      "buyer_accepts_marketing": false,
      "cancel_reason": null,
      "cancelled_at": null,
      "cart_token": null,
      "checkout_id": 20726986440841,
      "checkout_token": "65651fdv561165",
      "client_details": {
        "accept_language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "browser_height": 860,
        "browser_ip": "122.172.179.207",
        "browser_width": 1487,
        "session_hash": null,
      },
      "closed_at": null,
      "confirmed": true,
      "contact_email": null,
      "created_at": "2021-12-16T11:03:59+05:30",
      "currency": "INR",
      "current_subtotal_price": "500.00",
      "current_subtotal_price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "500.00",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "500.00",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        }
      },
      "current_total_discounts": "0.00",
      "current_total_discounts_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "0.00",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "0.00",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        }
      },
      "current_total_duties_set": null,
      "current_total_price": "600.00",
      "current_total_price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "600.00",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "600.00",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        }
      },
      "current_total_tax": "91.52",
      "current_total_tax_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "91.52",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "91.52",
          "currency_code": "INR"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can come up with an API call method (similar to which you already have done). The JSON which you are providing has different sub levels. So, you could use different classes for it. For simplification there are tools out there which converts JSON to Dart. You could look for them. Once such tool is [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).

API calling would most probably be just adding it in a root element. I guess it should take care of the rest. (because the inter dependency classes are also included when converting JSON to dart)

I tried to convert your JSON (which had an extra comma in line:19) and below is the result I got.

```dart
class Element {
  List<Orders> orders;

  Element({this.orders});

  Element.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['orders'] != null) {
      orders = new List<Orders>();
      json['orders'].forEach((v) {
        orders.add(new Orders.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.orders != null) {
      data['orders'] = this.orders.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Orders {
  int id;
  String adminGraphqlApiId;
  int appId;
  String browserIp;
  bool buyerAcceptsMarketing;
  Null cancelReason;
  Null cancelledAt;
  Null cartToken;
  int checkoutId;
  String checkoutToken;
  ClientDetails clientDetails;
  Null closedAt;
  bool confirmed;
  Null contactEmail;
  String createdAt;
  String currency;
  String currentSubtotalPrice;
  CurrentSubtotalPriceSet currentSubtotalPriceSet;
  String currentTotalDiscounts;
  CurrentSubtotalPriceSet currentTotalDiscountsSet;
  Null currentTotalDutiesSet;
  String currentTotalPrice;
  CurrentSubtotalPriceSet currentTotalPriceSet;
  String currentTotalTax;
  CurrentSubtotalPriceSet currentTotalTaxSet;

  Orders(
      {this.id,
      this.adminGraphqlApiId,
      this.appId,
      this.browserIp,
      this.buyerAcceptsMarketing,
      this.cancelReason,
      this.cancelledAt,
      this.cartToken,
      this.checkoutId,
      this.checkoutToken,
      this.clientDetails,
      this.closedAt,
      this.confirmed,
      this.contactEmail,
      this.createdAt,
      this.currency,
      this.currentSubtotalPrice,
      this.currentSubtotalPriceSet,
      this.currentTotalDiscounts,
      this.currentTotalDiscountsSet,
      this.currentTotalDutiesSet,
      this.currentTotalPrice,
      this.currentTotalPriceSet,
      this.currentTotalTax,
      this.currentTotalTaxSet});

  Orders.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    adminGraphqlApiId = json['admin_graphql_api_id'];
    appId = json['app_id'];
    browserIp = json['browser_ip'];
    buyerAcceptsMarketing = json['buyer_accepts_marketing'];
    cancelReason = json['cancel_reason'];
    cancelledAt = json['cancelled_at'];
    cartToken = json['cart_token'];
    checkoutId = json['checkout_id'];
    checkoutToken = json['checkout_token'];
    clientDetails = json['client_details'] != null
        ? new ClientDetails.fromJson(json['client_details'])
        : null;
    closedAt = json['closed_at'];
    confirmed = json['confirmed'];
    contactEmail = json['contact_email'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    currency = json['currency'];
    currentSubtotalPrice = json['current_subtotal_price'];
    currentSubtotalPriceSet = json['current_subtotal_price_set'] != null
        ? new CurrentSubtotalPriceSet.fromJson(
            json['current_subtotal_price_set'])
        : null;
    currentTotalDiscounts = json['current_total_discounts'];
    currentTotalDiscountsSet = json['current_total_discounts_set'] != null
        ? new CurrentSubtotalPriceSet.fromJson(
            json['current_total_discounts_set'])
        : null;
    currentTotalDutiesSet = json['current_total_duties_set'];
    currentTotalPrice = json['current_total_price'];
    currentTotalPriceSet = json['current_total_price_set'] != null
        ? new CurrentSubtotalPriceSet.fromJson(json['current_total_price_set'])
        : null;
    currentTotalTax = json['current_total_tax'];
    currentTotalTaxSet = json['current_total_tax_set'] != null
        ? new CurrentSubtotalPriceSet.fromJson(json['current_total_tax_set'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['admin_graphql_api_id'] = this.adminGraphqlApiId;
    data['app_id'] = this.appId;
    data['browser_ip'] = this.browserIp;
    data['buyer_accepts_marketing'] = this.buyerAcceptsMarketing;
    data['cancel_reason'] = this.cancelReason;
    data['cancelled_at'] = this.cancelledAt;
    data['cart_token'] = this.cartToken;
    data['checkout_id'] = this.checkoutId;
    data['checkout_token'] = this.checkoutToken;
    if (this.clientDetails != null) {
      data['client_details'] = this.clientDetails.toJson();
    }
    data['closed_at'] = this.closedAt;
    data['confirmed'] = this.confirmed;
    data['contact_email'] = this.contactEmail;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['currency'] = this.currency;
    data['current_subtotal_price'] = this.currentSubtotalPrice;
    if (this.currentSubtotalPriceSet != null) {
      data['current_subtotal_price_set'] =
          this.currentSubtotalPriceSet.toJson();
    }
    data['current_total_discounts'] = this.currentTotalDiscounts;
    if (this.currentTotalDiscountsSet != null) {
      data['current_total_discounts_set'] =
          this.currentTotalDiscountsSet.toJson();
    }
    data['current_total_duties_set'] = this.currentTotalDutiesSet;
    data['current_total_price'] = this.currentTotalPrice;
    if (this.currentTotalPriceSet != null) {
      data['current_total_price_set'] = this.currentTotalPriceSet.toJson();
    }
    data['current_total_tax'] = this.currentTotalTax;
    if (this.currentTotalTaxSet != null) {
      data['current_total_tax_set'] = this.currentTotalTaxSet.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ClientDetails {
  String acceptLanguage;
  int browserHeight;
  String browserIp;
  int browserWidth;
  Null sessionHash;

  ClientDetails(
      {this.acceptLanguage,
      this.browserHeight,
      this.browserIp,
      this.browserWidth,
      this.sessionHash});

  ClientDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    acceptLanguage = json['accept_language'];
    browserHeight = json['browser_height'];
    browserIp = json['browser_ip'];
    browserWidth = json['browser_width'];
    sessionHash = json['session_hash'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['accept_language'] = this.acceptLanguage;
    data['browser_height'] = this.browserHeight;
    data['browser_ip'] = this.browserIp;
    data['browser_width'] = this.browserWidth;
    data['session_hash'] = this.sessionHash;
    return data;
  }
}

class CurrentSubtotalPriceSet {
  ShopMoney shopMoney;
  ShopMoney presentmentMoney;

  CurrentSubtotalPriceSet({this.shopMoney, this.presentmentMoney});

  CurrentSubtotalPriceSet.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    shopMoney = json['shop_money'] != null
        ? new ShopMoney.fromJson(json['shop_money'])
        : null;
    presentmentMoney = json['presentment_money'] != null
        ? new ShopMoney.fromJson(json['presentment_money'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.shopMoney != null) {
      data['shop_money'] = this.shopMoney.toJson();
    }
    if (this.presentmentMoney != null) {
      data['presentment_money'] = this.presentmentMoney.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ShopMoney {
  String amount;
  String currencyCode;

  ShopMoney({this.amount, this.currencyCode});

  ShopMoney.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    amount = json['amount'];
    currencyCode = json['currency_code'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    data['currency_code'] = this.currencyCode;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay Sir, I will try that! thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

To call `API` your method is sufficient you just need to `return` value from your function according to the return type of your function. In your function you have a `return` type of `List<Element>` so you need to perform some changes in your code

```
Future<List<Element>> apiGetOrder() async{
  var response = await get(Uri.parse(MOCK_API_SMOOR_1));
  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body)["orders"];
  List<Element> elements = <Element>[];
  for(var i in jsonData){
    Element element = Element.fromJson(i);
    elements.add(element);
  }
  print(elements.length);

  return elements; // returning value
}
```

and for creating a `class` according to the `response` you can use a handy tool which **Quicktype** I'm also sharing link for the same

https://app.quicktype.io/